# Creating a custom XCode project template with subfolders

Tags: xcode, project-template

I have been playing with the project templates in order to create a custom template. I know how to create subgroups, even to create a empty folder represented by a group. But the problem comes when I try to create a more complicated structure with subfolders. The closest approach I got was with these lines of code inside the TemplateInfo.plist:

```
<key>Definitions</key>
<dict>
    <key>Parent</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Path</key>
        <string>Parent</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Parent/Child</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Group</key>
        <array>
            <string>Parent</string>
        </array>
        <key>Path</key>
        <string>Parent/Child</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>Nodes</key>
<array>
    <string>Parent</string>
    <string>Parent/Child</string>
</array>
```

But this is adding two references to the Child, one is pointing to the correct Child folder, and the other to the Parent.

P.S. Inside the .xctemplate I have also the empty folders same structured.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I answer myself hoping it will be helpful to somebody else.

Just defining the folder will list the rest of the content, so if it has a subfolder it will add it as a group to the project with its related link to the folder.

```
<key>Definitions</key>
<dict>
    <key>Parent</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Path</key>
        <string>Parent</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>Nodes</key>
<array>
    <string>Parent</string>
</array>
```

But this gives us another problem. In case of having files, it will recognize the last one as a folder producing kind of funny results.

[image]

I don't know if this is a bug of xcode or that I'm using kind of hack to list the subfolders.

I hope anybody else can find the solution to this problem.